# Cassandra Tombstones Not Being Removed By DTCS?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a Cassandra 2.1.4 cluster with 14 nodes. I am using it primarily for storing time series data collected via KairosDB.

The default TTL for data inserted into the column family named data_points (which is the biggest column family) is 12hrs. I have also set the gc_grace_seconds to 12 hrs.
In-spite of this my disk space keeps on increasing and it looks like tombstones are never dropped.

It looks like compactions are happening on a regular basis. The SSTable count does not seem outrageous either. It is constantly between ~10 to ~22. Compaction Strategy I am using is DTCS.

DESC keyspace -> http://pastebin.com/RW4rU76m

[image: Cassandra Disk Usage Over Time]

[image: Live SSTable Count]

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to mitigate this?

**UPDATE:** When I trigger a compaction manually, I see a drastic reduction in disk usage. It went from ~40GB to ~16GB. I also posted on the Cassandra user list and was suggested to move to a more recent version of Cassandra. Apparently in 2.1.4 this might be causing older data not to be dropped: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8359

Comment: BTW. How did you get those graphs? What tool do you use?

Comment: If you query for time series data older than 12h, do you get an empty response?

Comment: @Ralf: Yes, querying data over say 24 hrs, returns only the last 12hrs data. Meaning data that are older than 12hrs are not returned.

Comment: @piotrwest: https://signalfx.com/ :)

Comment: What parameters have you configured for DTCS: base_time_seconds, min_threshold, and max_sstable_age_days?